# Radio Button Validation Error

Tags: javascript, html, validation

For the gender radio button validation within the validate function below, the alert occurs whenever neither of the gender radio buttons are selected. However, whenever "ok" is selected within the browser, the form is submitted. What seems to be causing that problem? Also I would like for it to be focused like the rest when returned false, if that is possible.

JavaScript

```
 function validate()
{
var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender");
   if( document.myForm.firstname.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your first name!" );
     document.myForm.firstname.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
     if( document.myForm.lastname.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your last name!" );
     document.myForm.lastname.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
     if( document.myForm.email.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your email!" );
     document.myForm.email.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
     if( (gender[0].checked == false) && (gender[1].checked == false))
   {
     alert( "Please provide your gender!" );
     document.myForm.male.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
     if( document.myForm.date.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide a date to be performed!" );
     document.myForm.date.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
     if( document.myForm.vname.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide a victim's name!" );
     document.myForm.vname.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
     if( document.myForm.vemail.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide the victim's email!" );
     document.myForm.vemail.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   return( true );
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
<form action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi" name="myForm"  onsubmit="return(validate());">
<h1> Truth </h1>
<label> First Name: </label> <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" maxlength="30" placeholder="John" /> <br><br>
<label> Last Name: </label> <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Doe" /> <br><br>
<label> Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="user@mydomain.com" /> <br><br>
<label> Male </label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male"/>
<label> Female </label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"/> <br><br>
<label> Date to be performed: </label><input type="date" name="date" id="date" /><br><br>
<h2> Victim </h2>
<label> Name: </label>  <input type="text" name="vname" id="vname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Mary Jane" /><br><br>
 <label> Email:</label> <input type="text" name="vemail" id="vemail" placeholder="user@mydomain.com" /> <br><br>


    <h2> Please select a truth questions below </h2> <br>
<input type="radio" name="truth" value="q1"> Have you ever fallen and landed on your head? <br>

  <input type="radio"  name="truth" value="q2"> Have you ever return too much change? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q3"> Have you ever been admitted into the hospital? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q4"> Have you ever baked a cake? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q5"> Have you ever cheated on test? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q6"> Did you ever wish you were never born? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q7"> Did you ever hide from Sunday School? <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <br>
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with this issue?

Comment: @Stefan the submit doesn't work for jsfiddle.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to submit?

Comment: @misterManSam The validation works, the alert window within the browser pops up & says "Please provide your gender!" but after that, the submission goes through & disregards the remaining validations (i.e. date, victim's name, etc)

Comment: @Stefan Please see above^

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out the solution. Instead of having:

```
if( (gender[0].checked == false) && (gender[1].checked == false))
 {
  alert( "Please provide your gender!" );
     document.myForm.male.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
```

It should be:

```
  if( (gender[0].checked == false) && (gender[1].checked == false))
   {
     alert( "Please provide your gender!" );
     document.myForm.male.focus() ;
     return true;
   }
```

I did this & the validation is working perfectly.

Comment: It takes two days for me to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a default for gender.

`<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" checked/>`

This will avoid any possible confusion and requires less validation overall.

Comment: I am required to have validation for all fields.

Comment: @DanielleStewart then you don't want to trust javascript for this. That's something that should be done server-side. Client side javascript can be easily modified within the browser.

Comment: Oh no, this assignment is to test client side validation.

Comment: Oh... its homework. In any sort of production environment you'd never want to rely on client side code for validation purposes, so its a trivial requirement to be expected to validate everything client side.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your validate() function but I don't see you actually calling it when you submit the document. A submit input on it's own does not know about your validation.

Maybe change:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="if(validate==true) {document.forms[0].submit()}" />
```

Comment: Also your focus issue is because you are trying to focus on a control called "mail" which does not exist. Change it to focus on document.myForm.gender[0] and it should work.

Comment: I've figured out what the problem was. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I would select according to different IDs naming them male and female and and call the validate function as ElPedro suggests.

Comment: If you do this then they will be seen as two sets of radio buttons. The whole point about a radio button choice is that you can toggle between them and for this they have to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was issue with the focus function.
I made few changes and it worked.

```
<div id="box">
        <form action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi" name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validate();">
            <h1> Truth </h1>
            <label> First Name: </label> <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" maxlength="30" placeholder="John" /> <br><br>
            <label> Last Name: </label> <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Doe" /> <br><br>
            <label> Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="user@mydomain.com" /> <br><br>
            <label> Male </label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male"/>
            <label> Female </label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"/> <br><br>
            <label> Date to be performed: </label><input type="date" name="date" id="date" /><br><br>
            <h2> Victim </h2>
            <label> Name: </label>  <input type="text" name="vname" id="vname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Mary Jane" /><br><br>
            <label> Email:</label> <input type="text" name="vemail" id="vemail" placeholder="user@mydomain.com" /> <br><br>


            <h2> Please select a truth questions below </h2> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q1"> Have you ever fallen and landed on your head? <br>

            <input type="radio"  name="truth" value="q2"> Have you ever return too much change? <br>

            <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q3"> Have you ever been admitted into the hospital? <br>

            <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q4"> Have you ever baked a cake? <br>

            <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q5"> Have you ever cheated on test? <br>

            <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q6"> Did you ever wish you were never born? <br>

            <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q7"> Did you ever hide from Sunday School? <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <br>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <script>
        function validate(e)
        {
            var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender");
            if( document.myForm.firstname.value == "" )
            {
                alert( "Please provide your first name!" );
                return false;
            }
            if( document.myForm.lastname.value == "" )
            {
                alert( "Please provide your last name!" );
                 return false;
            }
            if( document.myForm.email.value == "" )
            {
                alert( "Please provide your email!" );
                 return false;
            }
            if( (gender[0].checked == false) && (gender[1].checked == false))
            {
                alert( "Please provide your gender!" );
                return false;
            }
            if( document.myForm.date.value == "" )
            {
                alert( "Please provide a date to be performed!" );
                 return false;
            }
            if( document.myForm.vname.value == "" )
            {
                alert( "Please provide a victim's name!" );
                 return false;
            }
            if( document.myForm.vemail.value == "" )
            {
                alert( "Please provide the victim's email!" );
                 return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**dont know if is the right answer but i uses that way and after evething i pass the variable value as my defined wish and passes to the form :)**

```js
var swticher = document.getElementById('swticher-on');
var swticher_off = document.getElementById('swticher-off');
function check(e){
    if(e.checked == swticher.checked)
    {
          // you can set the value for on as default by set valirable in it
          var val = swticher.value = "1";
          alert('on -> '+val);
       
     }
        else  if(e.checked == swticher_off.checked)
     { 
            // you can set the value for off as default by set valirable in it
            var val = swticher.value = "0";
            alert('off -> '+val); 
      }  
   }
```

```html
<!-- i dont know this is the right answer but i use this way somethings -->
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="radio" id="swticher-on" name="swticher" value="1" class="form-control swticher-in" onclick="check(this)">
     <label for="swticher-on">ON</label>
</div>  
                                          
<div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" id="swticher-off" name="swticher" value="0" class="form-control swticher-in" checked onclick="check(this)">
      <label for="swticher-off"><b class="text-danger">OFF</b></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation to your answer?